# How do I invoke an event on a Parent window from a Child window

Tags: javascript

I have a Parent window that displays information, including a link to open a Child window to edit the same information.  I want to be able to either refresh the Parent window or activate a button on the Parent to re-select the data, when the Child window is being closed.  Both programs are written in PHP.

The Parent program opens the Child window using the following JavaScript function:

```
function windowOpen(loadURL) {
      // In order to allow JavaScript to Close the Window, the Windows needs to be
      //  opened with JavaScript.  The URL to be loaded into the new Window is passed
      //  as a parameter.
    window.open(loadURL, "_blank");
}
```

The Child program currently uses this JavaScript function to close itself:

```
function windowClose() {
    window.open('','_parent','');
    window.close();
}
```

How do I change the windowClose() function to either: i) Refresh the Parent window; or ii) click a button on the Parent page that will re-select and re-display the page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve but try
[cross window communication](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication)